# Anaconda Installation on Azure Web App Services

Tags: python, azure, anaconda, virtualenv, azure-web-app-service

I install my python modules via pip for my Azure Web Apps. But some of python libraries that I need are only available in conda. I have been trying to install anaconda on Azure Web Apps (windows/linux), no success so far. Any suggestions/examples on how to use conda env on azure web apps?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure App Service only supports the official Python to be installed as extensions. Instead of using the normal App Service, I would suggest you to use a Webapp for Container so that you can deploy your web app as a docker container. I suppose this is the only solution until Microsoft supports Anaconda on App Service.

Comment: I realize that this question was asked a while ago, but do you know if there has been any update to this? Docker is not currently an option due to my workflow. Instead, I'm copying dependencies into a 'site-packages' folder in my wwwroot folder.

Comment: No Daniel. If you're using Python Extension on Windows App Service you'll still be able to do a pip install. But Micrsofot has withdrawn support for Python Extension. Their go to answer is either containers or Linux Web Apps with Python run time which is very simple to use

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Vijay! Is there a particular guide that you can recommend for deploying apps with containers & conda dependencies? By the way I've read your bio and the chatbot you are working on sounds fascinating.

Comment: I've not done this myself, but Docker with a miniconda should do well. Look at this https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-pip-and-docker-ftw-d64fe638dc45